# How can i use class attributes inside meta class in django

Tags: python, django

I have this code

```
class DistrictResource(ModelResource):
    model=models.District
    res_name="district"
    class Meta:
        queryset = self.model.District.objects.active()
```

how can i use `self.model` in meta as i get error if i use self

Comment: i would guess: just omit the self... seems like a class-attribute anyway.

Comment: if i do that , it says model is not defined , if i use that before the meta class then its ok but not inside meta class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
queryset = models.District.objects.active()
```

instead of

```
queryset = self.model.District.objects.active()
```

in this case.

Edit:

You *cannot* access `res_name` inside the inner class because of the rule of [scope resolution in Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html):

> A block is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class definition.
>
> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block.
>
> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this includes generator expressions since they are implemented using a function scope.

An easy rule to remember about Python Scope resolution is the LEGB rule:

L. Locals, i.e., names assigned within a function.

E. Enclosing function locals.

G. Globals

B. Built-ins.

---

`class Meta` is used by Django/Tastypie as configuration options when they use metaclass to construct the class. I am not sure why you would want to access a variable outside `Meta` from within `Meta`, rather than just define it inside `Meta`.

Comment: but why can i access the variables defined in upper class in meta class. is there any way . For.eg i can access `res_name` inside meta class

Comment: @user1787524 I've updated the answer to explain why you couldn't access `res_name`.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones still wanting to access a variable outside `Meta` from within `Meta`, one solution is to create the `Meta` class like this :

```
class DistrictResource(ModelResource):
    model=models.District
    res_name="district"
    Meta = type("Meta", (ModelBase,), {"foo": res_name, "queryset": model.objects.active()})
```

I've found this article giving knowledge about metaclasses : https://www.codingem.com/metaclasses-in-python/#Metaclasses_in_Python